# Running a complex query on semi-colon separated values in a column using regexp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table of content metadata. A few of the columns are user id, content id, roles. Roles column is ';' separated values. For example, 
[image]

In the above table, Outcome column indicates if the row should appear in the query or not.

Admin Roles: Admin, Implementor, setup
End user roles : End User 1, End User 2, End User 3, and so on. (these are dummy names, actual names are way different, can't disclose here).

To expand on further, the criteria is, the query should result rows, that have at least one non-admin end-user roles. There are five admin type roles and a ton of non-admin end-user roles. Row can have as many roles as possible.

Here are the approaches I am thinking:
1. Create a temp table with all the roles and query the table in where condition for roles and use INSTR to find out end-user roles. I do not want to do that, as I am trying to avoid pl/sql in my query. 
2. Regexp

I have been experimenting with regexp, but not getting anywhere with it.

**Note:** Please do not suggest changes in data layout, as I have no control over it!

**Update**:
Okay, here's another approach I am thinking. 
- Remove all the admin related roles from the column string.
- Check length of the list. Select non-zero length. 
I am guessing this will require 5 replace functions, one for each admin type roles and the one for counting length (which will essentially be counting number of semicolons +1).
I am trying this out. I will update my answer if it works. Else inviting more suggestions!

Comment: The Java-based RDBMS package HSQLDB, currently at version 2.4.0, offers  native ability to work with CSV text files.  If you are able to use it in your project, you can execute SQL queries against your CSV files via HSQLDB.

Comment: This isn't a csv file, it's just a column, with ';' saperated values.

Comment: Consider creating a table function that converts a list of roles to a table of roles. Then you can use straightforward sql.

Comment: @SejalParikh: Ok, so ... how would a CSV (comma separated value) file differ from a file with "columns with '.' separated values"?

Comment: You are right in a way. I can't use what you suggested though. I am using oracle apex, and I found apex_string api that I think will be useful for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: I am posting my final solution here, in case it may be of use to someone else:

```
with new_roles as 
(select id,
 roles,
trim(both ';' from (
    regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(roles, '(Setup)|(Administrator)|(Implementor)','')),
    ';{1;}',';'))) as role_new
 from my_table)

select id, roles, role_new
from new_roles
where (LENGTH(role_new) - LENGTH(REPLACE(role_new,';','')))+1 is not NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible, horrible data layout.  Let me assume that you cannot change it.  Sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really bad design decisions.

Let me also assume that the hierarchies on users only goes one-deep.  If so, you can use a single `join`:

```
select c.*,
       (case when ';' || c.roles || ';' like '%;Admin;%' then 'Yes'
             when ';' || cu.roles || ';' like '%;Admin;%' then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end) as Outcome
from content c left join
     content cu
     on ';' || c.roles|| ';' like '%;End User ' || cu.id || ';%';
```

EDIT:

If you have multiple admin roles, just use regular expressions:

```
select c.*,
       (case when regexp_like(';' || c.roles || ';', ';Admin;|;Implementor;|;Setup;') then 'Yes'
             when regexp_like(';' || cu.roles || ';', ';Admin;|;Implementor;|;Setup;') then 'Yes'
             else 'No'
        end) as Outcome
from content c left join
     content cu
     on ';' || c.roles|| ';' like '%;End User ' || cu.id || ';%';
```

Comment: Yes I can not change the data layout, you are right there. I think I confused you with my question. I have updated it with more clarification: Admin Roles: Admin, Implementor, setup End user roles : End User 1, End User 2, End User 3, and so on. (these are dummy names, actual names are way different, can't disclose here). --- So considering that, I am not sure if I could use your suggestion.

Comment: Are the actual end user roles repeats of the same string with incrementing numbers as in your example or are they a bunch of totally different words?

Comment: @rlog: Bunch of different words.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I experimented with the latest approach (updated in question), and it kind of works. I implemented with 3 admin roles. Had to use a long string manipulations for this. However, this will not work, if there are 3 consecutive admin roles listed (administrator;setup;implementer;end user 1) as I will have 3 ';' . Can someone suggest a better way to replace more than one semi-colons with a single one?

Also please suggest if there could be any improvement to this approach.

```
with new_roles as 
(select id,
 roles,
trim(both ';' from (replace(
    replace(
        replace(
            replace(roles,'Setup',''), 
            'Administrator', ''),
        'Implementor', ''),
    ';;', ';'))) as role_new
 from my_table)

select id, roles, role_new
from new_roles
where (LENGTH(role_new) - LENGTH(REPLACE(role_new,';','')))+1 is not NULL;
```